# Why does confusion matrix shows inverse output?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, logistic, classification, confusion-matrix

I am working on a logistic regression binary classification with 1000 rows and 28 columns

While I have split my dataset into `train` and `test`, I am using the `test` data to validate my model. After building the model, I got the below matrxi upon calling `.predict()`

Please find the confusion matrix below

```
[[  2  53]
 [  0 190]]
```

However, my label distribution (in test set) looks like below

```
status
0     55
1    190
```

As you can see that most of my labels are `1` but in confusion matrix above most of them are under `True Negative`. Shouldn't they be either under `True Positive`, `False negative`.

It doesn't make sense to see such a huge number under `True Negative`. because my actual negative is only 55 records as shown above

Am I making any mistake here? Can you guide me here? Am I constructing/interpreting the confusion matrix incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, your model predicted most units (except 2) into class 1, so this checks out (which is garbage, but that is a different issue).

| predicted\true | 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 53 |
| 1 | 0 | 190 |

Comment: Is there anyway to get the headers for my confusion matrix? Since, there is no headers, I thought the 1st column is always 1 and 2nd column is 0

Comment: May I also know what do you mean by `so this checks out`? I asl because my eng knowledge is limited

Comment: @TheGreat this checks out = this looks good. Anyway, I don't think you can print the labels, at least not easily. I assume you are using sklearn, in which case check https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html#sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.